# How do I tell libxml-ruby about external entity files?

Tags: validation, dtd, libxml2, libxml-ruby

I'm trying to validate using [libxml-ruby's `DTD#validate`](http://libxml.rubyforge.org/rdoc/classes/LibXML/XML/Dtd.html), but I keep getting the following warnings:

```
Warning: failed to load external entity "xhtml-lat1.ent" at :29.
Warning: failed to load external entity "xhtml-symbol.ent" at :34.
Warning: failed to load external entity "xhtml-special.ent" at :39.
```

I wouldn't mind, except I use things like `&hellip;`, which are defined in those, causing my XHTML to appear to be invalid.

How do I tell the DTD about those extra files?  I tried running from a directory containing the `.dtd` file and all of the `.ent`s, but that doesn't help.

Answer (score -1):

Reading the release notes I would suspect that you need to either use

```
XML.default_substitute_entities = true
```

or

```
XML.default_load_external_dtd = true
```

or both.

Comment: I'm having similar issues, and these options don't seem to have much (any?) effect.

Comment: Apologies - I'm not much of a ruby person (I'm an xml person). The docs seem to be particularly poor for libxml-ruby so I can't be of any more help